# dirpagination is working but not able to see controls

Tags: angularjs

The dirpagination works because it gives 10 items per row but I am not able to see the controls at the bottom of table to navigate.

//Creating tabs and table
`<div ng-controller="MyController" class="my-controller">
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Legislaotrs</h2> 
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> 
            <li><a href="#" class="active">By State</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">House</a></li> 
            <li><a href="#">Senate</a></li></ul> 
    </div> 
    <form class="form-inline"> 
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <label >Search</label> 
            <input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"> 
        </div> 
    </form> 
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover"> 
        <thead> 
        <tr>  <th>Party</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Chamber</th> <th>District</th> <th>State</th> </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody> 
        <tr dir-paginate="user in users|filter:search|itemsPerPage:10"> 
            <td> <img src="{{user.party_name}}" style="max-height: 10%;max-width: 10%;"/> </td> 
            <td>{{user.fullname}}</td> 
            <td > <img src="{{user.chamber_type}}" style="max-height: 8%;max-width: 7%;"/>{{user.chamber_name}} </td> 
            <td>{{user.district_name}}</td> 
            <td>{{user.state_name}}</td> 
            <td>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">View Details</button></td> 
        </tr> 
        </tbody> 
    </table>` 
//setting pagination controls
`<div id="paginate">
    <dir-pagination-controls 
    max-size="5" 
    direction-links="true" 
    boundary-links="true"> 
    </dir-pagination-controls></div>
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to include the module in your project:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
```

Then create the paginated content:

```
<dir-pagination-controls
[max-size=""]
[direction-links=""]
[boundary-links=""]
[on-page-change=""]
[pagination-id=""]
[template-url=""]>
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

here is working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview)